# undefined method `some_method' for "some_variable":String. Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to I'm trying to show table, but I get an error 
undefined method `name' for "Sphere Kharkov":String
This is my Instance Variables:

@result1 {"No department"=>"1", "Dep2"=>"1", "Sphere Kharkov"=>"2"}

@result2 {"Sphere Kharkov"=>"1"}

@department_names ["Sphere Kharkov", "Dep2", "Dep without members", "No department"]

Controller's methods

```
def age_profile
    @result1 = age_report(1,9)
    @result2 = age_report(10, 12)
    @department_names = current_company.departments.map(&:name)
    @department_names << "No department"
  end

def age_report(start_age, end_age)
      result = {}
      User.select("COALESCE(departments.name, 'No department') AS name, COALESCE(count( * ), '0') AS count")
      .joins("LEFT JOIN departments ON departments.id = users.department_id")
      .where(:users => { :is_deleted => 0, :company_id => current_company.id})
      .where("TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, `date_of_birth`, CURDATE()) BETWEEN :start_age AND :end_age", start_age: start_age, end_age: end_age)
      .group("departments.name")
      .each {|d| result[d.name] = d.count }
      result
    end
```

In View:

```
%table.table.table-striped.table-bordered
  %tr
    %th= t('Depatment')
    %th= t('1-18')
    %th= t('18-25')
    %th= t('25-45')

  -@department_names.each do |f|
    %tr
      %td= f.name
      %td= @result1[f.name]
      %td= @result2[f.name]
```

Сould you help me please. What's wrong?

Comment: just call `f`, not `f.name`: `%td= @result1[f]` & `%td= @result2[f]`

Comment: MrYoshiji, oh, thank you! It's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@department_names` variable contain strings that don't respond to `name` method. Simple solution is:

```
- @department_names.each do |f|
  %tr
    %td= f
    %td= @result1[f]
    %td= @result2[f]
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
 @department_names = current_company.departments.map(&:name)
```

Retrieves only the names of the companies. So basically you are calling the name method on the result of the name method.

So either remove `.map(&:name)` or just use `f` insteaf of `f.name`.